# Range.Find and With freezes Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Microsoft's entry in Range.Find function of VBA has the following code as an example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find):

```
   With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If 
End With
```

I tried to use it including the following With statement, but Excel froze.

```
   With Range("a1:f50")
     Set c = .Find("F-Value", LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            With c.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                     .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                     .ColorIndex = 0
                     .TintAndShade = 0
                     .Weight = xlThin
            End With
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
         Loop While Not c Is Nothing
     End If
 End With
```

I wonder if using both Range.Find and With make the code too heavy, because I bought the computer this year, and it runs fine overall.

Comment: You removed the `c.Address <> firstAddress` which is the only way to exit the loop

Comment: I don't understand. Why? Also, replacing the "With" statement with c.Value = 5 runs fine.

Comment: Setting the value to 5 will make sure that particular cell never gets found again (assuming itm <> 5) so the loop will eventually exit once all values have been replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You removed the `c.Address <> firstAddress` check, which is the only way to exit the loop in your use case.

`Find()/FindNext()` *always* loops around within your range until there's no matching value - when it gets to the end it just starts back at the beginning again.  How you account for that depends on what you do with the cell value after the cell has been located

- If you're replacing the value such that it will no longer be a match for the Find, you can exit the loop as soon as `Find()` fails to make a match and so returns `Nothing` (see second code example below)
- If you're *not* changing the cell value in the loop, then Find will just keep looping around, returning the same cells over and over, unless you have some way to exit the loop once all individual cells have been found.  Typically you do this by saving the address of the first cell, and then exiting the loop as soon as that cell is returned a second time.

So for your "no-replace" use case this works fine:

```vb
    Dim firstAddress As String, c As Range

    With Range("a1:f50")
         Set c = .Find("F-Value", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<<be specific
         If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address '<< remember the first cell found
            Do
                With c.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                         .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                         .ColorIndex = 0
                         .TintAndShade = 0
                         .Weight = xlThin
                End With
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
             Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress '<< exit once we've hit the first cell again
         End If
     End With
```

For comparison here's the "find with replace" version:

```vb
    Dim  c As Range

    With Range("a1:f50")
         Set c = .Find("F-Value", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
         Do While Not c Is Nothing
             c.Value = "SomeOtherValue"
             Set c = .FindNext(c)
         Loop 
    End With
```

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong code from Microsoft. I've changed it now. It seems c.Address is actually used, but only to create a variable named firstAddress. What would it be?

Comment: Also, writing firstAddress = c.Address in my code does not solve the problem

Comment: Would help to update your post with your actual code, including the Address part which is not working for you.  Your Microsoft code now looks wrong also - please provide a link for that example.

Comment: I've updated my code and provided the link for the Microsoft example

Comment: That example you posted is pretty bad and I'm not sure how what it's doing there: it "works" because the value is being replaced inside the loop, but the  `firstAddress = c.Address` line is completely redundant.