# Byref mismatch when using cell as Range argument

Tags: excel, vba

In the following VBA Excel subroutine, I want a range of cells to execute another subroutine called Valuation:

```
Sub Code_1()


With Range("a1:f50")
     Set c = .Find("target", LookIn:=xlValues)
     If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            Valuation c
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress
     End If
End With

End Sub
```

The Valuation subroutine is:

```
Sub Valuation(cell As Range)

cell.Value = 7
          
End Sub
```

Yet, when I run the code, I get the message: ByRef argument type mismatch. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best practice is to *always* declare your variables. Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module. Then, go to *Tools* > *Options* and check *Require Variable Declaration* to have `Option Explicit` automatically added going forward.

Since `c` is undeclared, it is a `Variant`, not a `Range`.

Note that the implicit `ByRef` should probably be an explicit `ByVal`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Code_1()

    Dim c As Range
    ...
    Dim firstAddress As String
    ...

End Sub

Sub Valuation(ByVal cell As Range)
    ...
End Sub
```

---

And as pointed out in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63237633/9245853) to your previous question, you need to adjust your loop if you're replacing the value after it's found, i.e, change:

```vb
Do
    Valuation c
    Set c = .FindNext(c)
Loop While c.Address <> firstAddress  '<~ this will error when there are no matches left
```

to

```
Do While Not c Is Nothing
    Valuation c
    Set c = .FindNext(c)
Loop
```

Comment: Changing Loop While to Loop freezes Excel. I believe this happens due to an infinite loop. See the discussion on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63237532/range-find-and-with-freezes-excel?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: That's exactly the question I linked to haha. If you're changing the value of `c` within the loop, then you can't use `Loop While c.Address <. firstAddress` because `FindNext` will eventually find no matches. When there's no match left, `c` will be `Nothing` and will not have an `Address`.